# checking equality of value from property file in JSP

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I am using property file for customizing messages, mean while I am setting priority in the property file, can I test the equality of priority in JSP using `<c:if>` tag. for message display in JSP I am using `<fmt:message>` tag.

eg:

in property file:

```
priority.key=1
```

in jsp:

```
<c:if "<fmt:message "priority.key"\> ==1" >Hi</c:if>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`<fmt:message>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/message.html) has a `var` attribute which allows you to set the bundle value as a page scoped variable.

```
<fmt:message key="priority.key" var="priorityKey" />
```

This way it's available by `${priorityKey}`. You could then just use it as such in the `<c:if>`.

```
<c:if test="${priorityKey == 1}">Hi</c:if>
```

Answer (score -1):

May be this combination will help you:

http://www.roseindia.net/jstl/jstl-el.shtml and
http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/simple-jsp-example/JSTLPropertyAccess.shtml

Personally for me it is very hard to understand your question. Please add more description or code.

Comment: Hi Dmitry                                                                I added code , since I did't format the code it is not displayed. I am using property file to set the priority 
eg priority.key = 1

In jsp I have to check the priority based on this I am displaying some message. In jsp I am using struts resource bundle for message cusotmization, I have used fmt:bundle, fmt:message tags for message display. and  c:if to check the condition.

Comment: Basically I wanted to know, how can I access the key from property file in side the c:if tag to check the condition??.

Comment: I think your code is still not visible. If you are using Struts 2 - read this about message bundles: http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-resource-bundle-example/. In struts 2 you are using mainly OGNL expression language rather then JSTL. Check this http://www.vaannila.com/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-ognl-expression-language-example-1.html

Comment: -1: roseindia.net is considered one of the worst Java EE learning resources. That site is cluttered of bad practices. See also http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/06/what-is-it-with-roseindia.html Also, you are basically actually not answering the question in detail.